# Powershell: Searching Content of files and write results to text file

Tags: search, powershell

I'm new to powershell so I don't know where to start. I want a script that searches in all (pdf, word, excell, powerpoint, ...) file content for a specific string combination.

I tried this script but it doesn't work:

```
function WordSearch ($sample, $staining, $sampleID, $patientID, $folder)
{
$objConnection = New-Object -com ADODB.Connection
$objRecordSet = New-Object -com ADODB.Recordset
$objConnection.Open(“Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=’Application=Windows’;”)
$objRecordSet.Open(“SELECT System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE ((Contains(Contents,’$sample’)) or (Contains(Contents,’$sampleID’) and Contains(Contents,’$staining’)) or (Contains(Contents,’$staining’) and Contains(Contents,’$patientID’))) AND System.ItemPathDisplay LIKE ‘$folder\%’”, $objConnection)
if ($objRecordSet.EOF -eq $false) {$objRecordSet.MoveFirst() }

while ($objRecordset.EOF -ne $true) {
$objRecordset.Fields.Item(“System.ItemPathDisplay”).Value
$objRecordset.MoveNext()
}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you use `select-string` ?

Comment: @C.B. because this works fine for text files, but when you want to search within .doc or especially .docx it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, but first make sure your in the folder you want to start searching down: (if your trying to search your whole computer, start in C:\ , but I imagine the script will take a decent amount of time to run.

```
$Paths = @()    
$Paths = gci . *.* -rec | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } |? {($_.Extension -eq ".doc") -or ($_.Extension -eq ".ppt") -or ($_.Extension -eq ".pdf") -or ($_.Extension -eq ".xls")} | resolve-path
```

This will retrieve all the file paths of those file types. If you have Microsoft office 2007 or above you may want to add searches for ".xlsx" or ".docx" or ".pptx"

Then you can begin looking through those files for your "specific string combination

```
array = @()
foreach($path in $Paths)
{$array += Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern "Search String"}
```

This will give you all the lines and paths that that string exists on in those files. The actual line output you get may be a little distorted though due to microsoft encrypting their files. Use  `$array | get-member -MemberType Property` to find what items you can index to and the `Select-object` commandlet to pull those items out.

Comment: This will work fine for text files, xls and so on... but use this on a docx and it will not work.

Comment: Why not? Have you ever looked at a docx file with a text editor? All the text is still in the file, its not in some magical place. Docx just has a lot of extra metadata for formatting, pictures, ect. But all the text is still searchable. Try it.

Comment: What you said is true of .doc on my system, I am able to see the original text allbeit mixed in with all the other symbols and rubbish, but this is not true of my .docx files

Comment: Ah i see your point. Guess you'd have to open up the file in winword and resave as doc to get it to work